# How to traverse a nested list in an optional?

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have an object `node` which has a `getNodes()` method that returns a list, and I want to traverse this list only if `node` is not `null`.

I tried to do the following where I thought I could map the stream of the list and traverse it, but what happens is that it tries to perform the filter on the Stream Object and not on the contents of the list.

```
public void updateNode(Node node) {
    List<Node> nodes = Optional.ofNullable(node)
                   .map(node -> Stream.of(node.getNodes))
                   .filter().......orElse()

    // operation on filtered nodes.
    ....

}
```

Comment: Why are you returning something in a `void` method? What is the method supposed to return?

Comment: if (null == node) return; Does not it work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the worst of the implementation choices, to the [correct answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60890756/1746118) to place a `null` check one has the following alternates available:

```
Optional.ofNullable(node)
        .map(Node::getNodes)
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        .stream() // Stream of nodes
        .filter(...)
```

or with Java-9 +

```
Stream.ofNullable(node)
        .flatMap(nd -> nd.getNodes().stream())
        .filter(...)
```

Comment: Great thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Is this the worse the implementation out of the two (null checking before hand in an if statement)?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably better off just using a simple if not null statement than introducing an optional.  It makes the code more readable and reduces overhead.

```
if (node != null) {
    node.getNodes().stream.filter(...
}
```

Also, you are returning from a void method.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
 Optional.ofNullable(node).map(node -> Stream.of(node.getNodes))
```

This creates a stream of a single item: the list of nodes itself.

```
Stream.of(node.getNodes))
```

Instead of that, to get a stream of the nodes, where you can then filter the node, use:

```
node.getNodes().stream().filter(...
```

Comment: `Stream.of(node.getNodes))` would thrrow a null pointer exception for `node==null`

Comment: @Naman `Optional.ofNullable(node)` returns `Optional.empty` when node == null. The OP's code will not call the mapper function.